# Completely disable the call mode sound channel

Tags: audio

This seems a regular issue to a lot of people without a true fix. The bad sound quality when in a call trought the Discord app.

For what I can understand, it is caused but the channel : the "phone sound channel" or "call mode" .

It seems that Discord had an option to switch between the two modes but that option has been removed.

So I'm looking at a more drastic solution : disabling the call mode channel entierly. And forcing every app to push their audio to the communication mode channel.

Is that possible ?

To me, this feature does not make any sense anyway. Why would you need a channel that not only lower every sounds you are listening to (including the voice of the person you are speaking with) **as well** as lowering the audio quality of your own microphone. If someone is knowlagable about why such thing exist, I would be very curious to know the explaination. On a practial sense, this feature confuse me a lot.

An funny addition : I use an app to track the kilometers I do during my walks. For every kilometers done, a voice announce the number, the time, ... When the voice is speaking, the channels are switched and the quality is suddently perfect. When the voice has finished, everything goes back to 2000 phone call quality. It shows that the phone is perfecly capable to handle the sound and that another app can trigger the switch.